# Image change onclick Javascript, can I add a timer to change as well?

Tags: javascript

Edit: is there anyway to have the interval only kick in if the user has not clicked? example: I set a interval of 20 seconds, but if the user had clicked the first image at 15 seconds, the next image only shows up for the remaining 5 seconds. I need a timer -or- a click but not both. Thanks!

So I have the javascript below that currently works onclick. Can it be modified to also add a timer? So if they don't click on the first image, I can set a timer to go to image 2.. then to image 3.. and so on. Thx for your efforts!

```
<img alt="" src="image1.gif" style="height: XXXpx; width: XXXpx" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()"  />

<script language="javascript">
    function changeImage() {

        if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "image1.gif") 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "image2.gif";
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "image3.gif";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` to call the `changeImage` function at intervals.

This should work:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function changeImage() {
        var img = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");
        img.src = (img.src == 'image1.gif') ? 'image2.gif' : 'image3.gif';
    }

    // auto-trigger every 1 second, change 1000 as needed
    setInterval(changeImage, 1000);
</script>
```

*Note*: Modified the code to make it smaller.

Comment: is there anyway to have the interval only kick in if the user has not clicked? example: I set a interval of 20 seconds, but if the user had clicked the first image at 15 seconds, the next image only shows up for the remaining 5 seconds. I need a timer -or- a click but not both. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use `setInterval`

```
setInterval(function() { changeImage(); }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this snippet below it picks a random image after a set time -

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
          var intTimer=0;

          function ImageRotate()

          {
              intTimer = self.setInterval("GenerateRandom()",3000);
          }

          function GenerateRandom()
          {
          var intNumber = 10;  
          var intRandom = 0;

              intRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * intNumber + 1);

              document.getElementById("ImageRandom1").src = 
              "Pictures1/Image" + intRandom + ".JPG";

      }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your images in to array and than with setInterval call your function like this
[jsBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/uyeves/5/edit)

**Edited!** *updated*

```
var i = 0,
    element = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange"),
    images = ["image1.gif", "image2.gif", "image3.gif"],
    timer = setInterval(changeImage, 25000);      

function changeImage() {
    element.src = images[(i >= images.length) ? (i = 0) : i++];
}

element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    changeImage();
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = setInterval(changeImage, 25000);
}, false);
```

Comment: is there anyway to have the interval only kick in if the user has not clicked? example: I set a interval of 20 seconds, but if the user had clicked the first image at 15 seconds, the next image only shows up for the remaining 5 seconds. I need a timer -or- a click but not both. Thanks!

Comment: if I understood you correctly you want to setInterval again from 0?
if so i'll make some changes to code

Comment: yes, exactly, i want a timer if no click and if they do click, the timer resets to set interval... I tried your code and could not get it to work unfortunately.

Comment: @UnreelWorld can you provide your code in jsFiddle or in jsBin ?

Comment: So exactly what I am looking for is... the user is presented with an image. If the user doesn't click, in 20 seconds it changes to next image. If user does, the next image also has a 20 second timer or a click. Currently the timer starts and if the user click say at 15 seconds, the next image changes at 5 seconds. I need each image to have it's own 20 second timer. thx!